# Why I've this error with my prefix in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, prefix

I recently started to develop a discord bot in python and there is an error that I do not understand

What I want: I want to be able to have as a prefix the mention of the bot and a prefix which is drawn from a JSON file

My problem: I've this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 942, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 938, in process_commands
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 875, in get_context
    raise TypeError("Iterable command_prefix or list returned from get_prefix must "
TypeError: Iterable command_prefix or list returned from get_prefix must contain only strings, not function
```

Here's my code:

```py
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open(prefix_file, 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    pref_fin =  prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
    return pref_fin
 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = when_mentioned_or(get_prefix), description = "Bot by Cucus#0001",intents=intents)
```

I don't understand because my function get_prefix() return a string

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Please post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - they include a lot of valuable information and are critical to debugging.

Comment: Also, see this guide to creating a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need a *complete* example including the data and all imports/definitions in order to debug. When producing such an example, try to narrow the problem to the exact issue and strip out unnecessary detail, while making sure the code is still complete and executable.

Comment: you gave the function get_prefix as an argument you probably meant something like get_prefix(client, message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `when_mentioned_or` function incorrectly.

```py
async def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open(prefix_file, 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    pref_fin = prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
    return when_mentioned_or(pref_fin)(client, message)
```

And then use can use it:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, description="Bot by Cucus#0001",intents=intents)
```